# Why im not receiving data to php? Undefined index

Tags: php, ajax, cordova

I'm trying to send a value from my phonegap app via ajax to php and then check that value with my sql db. Now since there is an undefined index gli2 the php file won't even receive or send data to my sql db, but it will give me the result 'You can eat'. Can somebody help my ?

Here is my php file:

```
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$gli2 = $_POST['gli2'];

$result = $conn->query("SELECT smt FROM product WHERE smt='${gli2}' and BarCode =0");

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if ($row['smt'] == '0' ) {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("You can eat")';
echo '</script>';
}else{
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("You cannot eat")';
echo '</script>';
}
?>
```

And here is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://localhost/test/testing.php',
    data: {gli2: document.getElementById("galima1").value,},
        success: function() {
   console.log('success');
  },
  dataType: 'application/json',

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong syntax here:

```
smt='${gli2}'
```

You need to use, for inline variable expansion:

```
smt='{$gli2}'
```

So that the full code becomes:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT smt FROM product WHERE smt='{$gli2}' and BarCode=0");
```

It is also better (not compulsory) to use backticks for better readability and safety.

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT `smt` FROM `product` WHERE `smt`='{$gli2}' and `BarCode`=0");
```

See the position of the `{` and `$`. This is not like Rails or other templating engines. Also, your code is susceptible to **SQL Injection Attack**. It would be better to pass `$gli2` to the built-in function [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to get it cleaned.

Comment: Thanks for the correction and explanation, but still no data is getting into my php file. Going to check all of my syntax, maybe there is more than 1 mistake made.

Comment: @dziugas009 No data will get into your DB, because it is just a `SELECT` query and not an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` query. Can you be clear in what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks @Pravven Kumar, since you mentioned the inesert query, I figured it out :), now it works fine

Answer (score 1):

The variable in query `${gli2}` does not evaluate to anything.

As it has a curly brace after `$` sign.

Change

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT smt FROM product 
WHERE smt='${gli2}' and BarCode =0");
```

To

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT smt FROM product 
WHERE smt='{$gli2}' and BarCode =0");
```

Comment: You must explain something.